# How to handle database transaction lag in UI to provide good user experience?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing social feature in my android app and I'm wondering how to deliver good user experience.

When user clicks "VoteUp" button, I'm waiting for a firebase realtime database transaction completes.
Since this is asynchronous network call, it takes a while.

My actual code updates UI on transaction completed. But there is annoying delay between user interaction and UI update.

Should I update UI (calculate and update counters, change button state) at the client side assuming that the transaction will be successful? If so, how to handle errors in that scenario?

Comment: Firebase Update UI by it self if you observe data on valueEventListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you should not do that because the user is confused if it did not work. Display some sort of progressbar. Since the network request takes an indeterminate amount of time to complete, show an indeterminate progressBar. You could for example display one inside the VoteUp button and disable it. Once the request finishes just show the result.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, but still looks weird from the user perspective. I have never seen progressbar on VoteUp button pressed in similar applications. Is there is a way to avoid progressbar?

Comment: Yes you can do that! You could do it in a similar way like instagram does it with comments: They show the comment in very light grey when you post it and it will turn to the regular color once it is posted on the server successfully. Maybe this is a way you are looking for?